# Bundle products are always out of stock and price shows 0

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento website based on commmunity edition 1.7.0.2. I have two problems with bundle products on product page , they are:

1.) Price is zero on product page and not getting updated on selecting bundle items.

Error on firebug console :

```
    ReferenceError: bundle is not defined
    [Break On This Error]   
    bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)
```

2.) Bundle products are always out of stock.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's not calling bundle.phtml !!

Answer (score 0):

while creating bundle products , try to select SKU,Weight and Price as dynamic.
And add a simple product which is in stock.
Refer [Link 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product).
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I have checked it is already done this way. can you suggest me why this error is coming ?